# Hilbert space is orthornormality needed for representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In a Hilbert space $H$ with countable basis, if I know there is a countable basis $\{h_n\}$ of $H$ then can I express every element $h\in H$ therein as:
\begin{equation}
h = \sum_n \langle h,h_n\rangle h_n?
\end{equation}

Comment: In what sense are you referring to the word "basis"? Hamel basis or orthogonal basis as in total orthogonal sequence?

Comment: Minimal spanning set (I think it's called a Hamel basis)

Comment: Span in algebraic sense? Like every $h\in H$ can be written as a __finite__ sum of elements in $\{h_n\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple example to demonstrate the importance of the basis being orthonormal, consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard inner product and the basis $h_1=(1,0)$ and $h_2=(1,1)$. If $h=(0,1)$ then
$$ h=-h_1+h_2 $$
but $\langle h,h_1\rangle=0$.

By the way, a Hilbert space basis of $H$ is different from a basis of $H$ as an abstract vector space (called a Hamel basis). The latter is generally much larger, as only finite linear combinations of the elements are permitted.

Comment: Ah, ok but at the end of the day there exists a unique set of scalars $\{c_n\}$ such that $h = \sum_n c_n h_n$ though right?

Comment: Yes, though as I said in my answer you need to be careful about what type of basis you're working with.

Comment: I just noticed your user-name carmichael561 includes the first Carmichael number.

Answer (score 1):

Re : The proposer's comment to carmichael561's answer: Let $\{e_n:n\in N\}$ be an orthonormal Hilbert-space basis for $H.$ Let $h_1=e_1$ and $h_2=e_1-e_2. $  For $n\geq 3$ let $h_n=e_1+2e_{n-1}-e_n.$ Then $e_1$ has two representations with respect to $\{h_n: n\in N\},$ namely $$(i) \quad e_1=h_1.$$  $$(ii) \quad e_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} h_n 2^{-n}.$$

Comment: Cool!  Very useful remark/ answer.  Thanks!